# Move the period outside the quotes on the site-analytics page

Tags: feature-request, bug, wording, localization, site-analytics

If you don’t have 25k reputation, the [site-analytics page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) contains a stub text:

> [image: "The page you're trying to visit requires the privilege "access to the site analytics."]

As you can see on the image, the dot should be moved outside the quotes. Also, on ruSO we need to [change the quote style](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6495/176217) from `“”` to `«»`, but this is not possible via Transifex, because there is no full sentence available to translate.

Comment: Dot is not part of design, maybe wording. :)

Comment: Technically that's the grammatically correct way to say it.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat ... in the US.

Answer (score 4):

The same could be said about `/tools` page for users under 10K.

But as mentioned in comments, this placement of punctuation is common in American English. See, for example,

- [When should end punctuation go inside quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7548/when-should-end-punctuation-go-inside-quotes)
- [How should I punctuate around quotes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/how-should-i-punctuate-around-quotes)

(Coincidentally or not, the latter question was asked by a Stack Exchange employee.)