# Extra comma in search results

Tags: bug, search, wording

If you search option doesn't give a results, such option is used as a text, i.e. quotified. In this case there is an extra comma in the sentence. E.g. searching with option [`user:0`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A0):

> [image: comma]

I hope that there is no [US-specific rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303973/339911).

Comment: +1 for US specific rules ... let's annoy the heck out of them ;)