# Too many full stops…

Tags: bug, badges, information-display, badge-description

This has got to be the smallest text correction request ever…

…but as noticed in a question on English Language Learners - [Should a full stop punctuation be used in Abbreviations?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344728/should-a-full-stop-punctuation-be-used-in-abbreviations) - there are too many full stops [periods] at the end of the [Enthusiast Badge description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/enthusiast).

> [image: badge description with the extra full stop]

The one outside the brackets needs to go bye-bye.

<sup>No hurry, I'm sure people have better things to do ;)</sup>

Comment: Worth to mention it's fine in the [badges list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Comment: The brackets don't even need to be. What's wrong with just ending with *Days are counted in UTC.*

Comment: [My 6yo related report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300444/339911)

Comment: And [one more interesting moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303973/339911) regarding dots here.

Comment: Too many full stops, plural? How about "*Visit the site each day for 30 consecutive days (days are counted in UTC).*"?

Comment: @Joachim - which probably got edited at some point to make the parenthetical note stand alone, but they didn’t delete the last period after properly putting one inside the parens.

Comment: As editing tags doesn't allow an edit summary, here it is:  punctuation (no tag) and spelling (the tag which was replaced) are two different things.

Comment: lol even the edits here are really minor. :-D